# How to indicate I finished top of my class on a UK-format CV?

Tags: resume, united-kingdom

I'm modifying my CV to a UK format, and I would like to mention that I've participated in a course and finished as one of the top students.

How do you go about indicating this on UK CV (if at all)?

Thanks!

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings Ha, I was referred here by the English usage and language stack exchange!

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks for your answer, I just haven't seen that kind of phrase in the UK, so I thought it is more common in the US. I guess that's OK then!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Class rank" isn't really a common thing in the UK so it would be very unusual to see on a UK CV, instead you would just list the grade or score. Unless the course was particularly difficult and prestigious (and your intended hiring audience would appreciate both those aspects) then I would leave it off.